# adding child entities in oneToMany single sided join table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

My entity like..

```
@Entity
public class parent{
@id
private string id;
private string name;
@OneToMAny
List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();

//getters n setters
}
```

after saving parent if I want to add child then I need to do like

```
Parent parent = parentRepository.findOne(parentId);     
if(parent != null){
      parent.getChildren().add(new Child("Id","name"));
}
```

as we can see I need to fetch all children by parent.getChildren() first then add a new,suppose I ve bulk record in child table,is it the appropriate way to add child??
Is there any good way to add new child.
I can't use oneToMAny mapped By here, cuz there are some more entity which holds same child entity(Child) as child List,so I can not modify my child entity by adding foreign key column and I ve to go with joinTable only.I am using jpa+Spring+Hibernate

Comment: The fact that you can't add a foreign key doesn't prevent you from making the association bidirectional. You'll simply have to map it using `@JoinTable` to tell JPA that you want a join table rather than a join column.

Comment: thank you for yr comment,I had no idea about we can also specify JoinTable in ManyToOne side.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear :/ but from what I understand :

One parent have many children. One child have many parent.

It's a many-to-many relation.

You can do :

Entities : Parent, Child, ParentChild

- Parent = OneToMany of type ParentChild
- Child = OneToMany of type ParentChild
- ParentChild = ManyToOne of type Parent and Child

You can persist ParentChild alone without fetching list.

Or you can have a recursive table.

- Person : ManyToOne of his parent.